# Where to obtain JSP support jar files for Jetty

Tags: java, jsp, jetty

I created a web application in Netbeans using the default Glassfish server bundle but I would like to deploy the generated WAR file in Jetty.

I realized that JSP support was not available when I deploy the WAR file generated by Netbeans when deploying the WAR file on Jetty (using start.jar as a Standalone Server) due to missing JAR files that are suppose to enable JSP support as Netbeans doesn't actively package these essential JAR files for JSP support when packaging the WAR distribution.

Where do I download all the necessary JAR files to enable JSP support for Jetty ?

Comment: Use plugin http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/54458/jetty-server-nb-1-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In standalone jetty, just enable the `jsp` module in your chosen `${jetty.base}` instance configuration directory.

Note: Do not modify / edit / change / delete / add / remove any content in your `jetty-home` directory (or the `jetty-distribution` directory if you are still using the older artifact).